# Duplicate Content Management

Tags: kentico, kentico-kontent

I have bunch of duplicate content errors to fix. Same content have different links. Or some have only one duplicate content error. Whats the easy way to fix. Its hurting SEO really badly.

I have tried to use 301 redirect which already active but I also know that using rel="canonical" link can fix but need clear explanation on how to use and where to use, is it in source?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have actual duplicate content in the content tree or you just have multiple URL alias for the same content page?

If you have duplicate content in the tree, delete the duplicates.

If you have multiple URL alias for the same page, then set the [alias redirection behavior to be "redirect to main URL"](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/configuring-page-urls/setting-page-aliases). This way, search engine will know those aliases are 301 redirect to main URL.

Comment: so if I redirect page aliases to main url is it going to reduce the errors.

Comment: At least from a crawler point of view, those duplicated links to a page are 301 redirects, not duplicate link to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Using canonical links is the best option in your case. Canonical links help Google to understand what URL is main for your content. Follow this [official Google instruction](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it makes sense to have duplicates in the content tree.  BUT you need to take caution as to how to deal with them.  As Rui stated, make sure the setting is set to "redirect to the main URL".

Also, implement a canonical link web part on the master page. There is one on the [Kentico Marketplace](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/canonical-meta-tag-web-part) which is really robust and works well.